# Why does clicking the login button result in a redirection to the wrong page?

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

When I click the login button, it redirects me to the wrong page. Why? The code does not behave the way it is intended to.

Login Page:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>

  <body>
     <form method='post' action='registration.php'>
        <table width='400' border='5' align='center'>
//when i hit login , it redirects to wrong page
          <tr>
               <td colspan='5' align='center'><h1>Login Form</h1></td>
          </tr>
/* I don't know what is wrong with this code */


          <tr>
               <td align='center'>Password:</td>
               <td><input type='password' name='pass' /></td>
          </tr>
//when i hit login , it redirects to wrong page
          <tr>
               <td align='center'>Email:</td>
               <td><input type='text' name='email' /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
               <td colspan='5' align='center'><input type='submit' name='login'      value='Login' /></td>
          </tr>

                 //login button not working
        </table>


     </form>

  <center><font color="red" size="5"><a href="registration.php">
    Sign Up Here</a></font></center> 

  </body>  

</html>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("users_db");
//when i hit login , it redirects to wrong page
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
   $password = $_POST['pass'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

   $check_user = "select * from users where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";

   $run = mysql_query($check_user);
//when i hit login , it redirects to wrong page
   if (mysql_num_rows($run)>0) {

     echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
   }
   else  {
     echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect')</script>";
   }

}  //when i hit login , it redirects to wrong page

?>
```

Comment: Which page is redirecting to?

Comment: Your entire script is very wrong.. you might consider refactoring it entirely.. take a look here: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, when you click "Login" you should end up on a page called "registration.php" which I assume does something like this :-

```
<?php // registration.php

$pass  = $_POST['pass']; // NOTE: Every hacker on the planet can see
$email = $_POST['email']; // this, so use some kind of filtering !

// Match $pass & $email to record in table
// If match print welcome and set-up session
// else print Email or password is incorrect

?>
```

Comment: Yes , I end up at registration.php  . But I want to end up at login.php page . What should I do?

Comment: @NakulYadav change the action attribute in your form to `action='login.php'`

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few items to fix:

- A robust approach to redirecting employs code like this:

  ```
  header('Location: http://example.com/dir');
  exit();
  ```

  JavaScript as a redirection device will generally work, but it's rather brittle - the page is fully loaded before it executes, whereas a header is acted upon by the browser earlier.
- To get that to work, you need to handle it *before* HTML output (at the start of the script) not after it. To do this, move your PHP block to the start of the file.
- You also have SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code - to fix this either escape your user input, using `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])`, or better yet swap to a newer database library, and use parameter binding.
- When the user gets the credentials correct, it is normal to set a session variable to indicate this - presently you're just redirecting to another page. What's to stop the user just going there directly?
- It looks like you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not a good practice, since if the database is stolen by hackers, any of your users who reuse their email/password combinations in other popular sites are at risk of further hacking. You should use a strong hash and salting approach, such as that provided by `password_hash()`.